# Failed in native DLL. HRESULT=0x80080014

Tags: c#, wpf

InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code.

Failed in native DLL. HRESULT=0x80080014.

The error was produced when I try to run the program. The error code is in bold....

```
public PoseViewModel()
        {
            if (!IsInDesignMode)
            {
                _leftHandImage = DefaultleftHand;
                _rightHandImage = DefaultrightHand;
                _skeletons = new List<SkeletonData>();
                _runtime = new Runtime();

                _runtime.SkeletonFrameReady += RuntimeSkeletonFrameReady;
                _runtime.VideoFrameReady += RuntimeVideoFrameReady;
                **_runtime.Initialize(RuntimeOptions.UseSkeletalTracking | RuntimeOptions.UseColor);**
                _runtime.VideoStream.Open(ImageStreamType.Video, 2, ImageResolution.Resolution640x480, ImageType.Color);
                Messenger.Default.Register<CommandMessage>(this, ProcessSpeechCommand);
                SpeechController.Initialize();
                //IsTracking = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Kinect isn't connected to your PC: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/kinectsdknuiapi/thread/2e5c176d-4b84-4749-b010-5e1f7fd14bd1